# Cisco ASA. NAT и проброс портов от нескольких публичных IP

Tags: nat, cisco

Имеется *Cisco ASA 5520*. На ней поднят *NAT*. Необходимо чтобы *ASA* имела несколько публичных IP-адресов и определённые порты с этих адресов "пробрасывались" внутрь локальной сети на сервера. При этом существующую функциональность необходимо сохранить. Можно ли это сделать и если можно, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В прошивках *Cisco ASA* версии ниже 8.3 такое сделать невозможно. Можно сделать *static NAT*, когда *ASA* все обращения с одного внешнего IP-адреса "пробрасывает" на один сервер в локальной сети. При использовании *static NAT* *ASA* может иметь более одного публичного IP-адреса, но при этом функциональность *NAT* будет отключена, т.е. использовать *ASA* как шлюз для локальной сети станет невозможно.

Однако, в прошивках версии 8.3 и выше необходимый функционал присутствует. Вот основа конфигурации, решающей данную задачу:

```
! Интернет-интерфейс.
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
    nameif outside
    security-level 0
    ip address 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0

! Интерфейс внутренней сети.
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
    nameif inside
    security-level 100
    ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

! Шлюз по умолчанию.
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.2.3.1 1

! Проброс портов на основном IP-адресе.
object network IP1_SERVER1
    host 192.168.1.2
    nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 80 80

! Проброс портов на втором IP-адресе.
object network IP2_SERVER1
    host 192.168.1.3
    nat (inside,outside) static 1.2.3.5 service tcp 80 80

! Правила пропуска пакетов из внутренней сети (разрешено всё).
access-list ALLOW_FROM_INTERNAL extended permit ip any any

! Правила пропуска пакетов из сети Интернет.
access-list ALLOW_FROM_INTERNET extended permit tcp any object IP1_SERVER1 eq 80
access-list ALLOW_FROM_INTERNET extended permit tcp any object IP2_SERVER2 eq 80

! "Вешаем" правила на интерфейсы.
access-group ALLOW_FROM_INTERNET in interface outside
access-group ALLOW_FROM_INTERNAL in interface inside
```

Таким образом можно "пробрасывать" порты с любого количества публичных IP-адресов, причём разные порты можно "пробрасывать" на разные внутренние адреса.

---

Если правил много, то вместо указания конкретного адреса в ***каждом*** правиле `nat`, можно создать `object network` и указывать в правилах именно его:

```
object network WAN_IP_2
    host 1.2.3.5

object network IP2_SERVER1
    host 192.168.1.3
    nat (inside,outside) static WAN_IP_2 service tcp 80 80
```

Такой подход позволит при смене адресации не "перелопачивать" весь конфиг, а поменять адрес в одном месте.

---

P.S. Работоспособность проверялась на *Cisco ASA 5520* с прошивкой версии 9.1(3).